# How do I repair malformed Banshee database?

Tags: banshee

My laptop ended up getting unplugged and powered off while Banshee was importing media files. When I turned it back on and logged into my linux mint 15 I tried to open banshee but got a fatal error.  I completely removed banshee using package manager then rebooted.  I then used software manager to reinstall Banshee but when i tried to open it I got the same fatal error.

> Fatal Error Details:
>
> An unhandled exception was thrown: Sqlite error 11: database disk image is malformed (SQL: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CoreTracks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete its local database: `rm -f ~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db`. It should be reconstructed the next time you run Banshee.